# TIF file too large for rasterio in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tiff, rasterio

I'm very inexperienced with python and I'm trying to process a TIF file with rasterio that gives the elevation data for half of Australia, this is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio

path = 'nationalz54ag.tif'

with rasterio.open(path) as f:
    arr = f.read(1)
    mask = (arr != f.nodata)
    elev = arr[mask]
    col, row = np.where(mask)
    x, y = f.xy(col, row)
    uid = np.arange(f.height * f.width).reshape((f.height, f.width))[mask]

result = np.rec.fromarrays([uid, x, y, elev],
                           names=['id', 'x', 'y', 'elev'])

print(result.dtype)
print(result[:10])
```

but it returns this error:

```
File "C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\Desktop\Schoolwork\IB\Extended Essay\Mesh\tiff file print.py", line 7, in <module>
    arr = f.read(1)
  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 590, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 251. GiB for an array with shape (1, 642397, 105002) and data type float32
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

> I wanted to run different code through GDAL but installing that plugin is creating  wealth of problems. Is there a way to run this TIF file or is it just too big?